# Get diode voltage

Tags: voltage, diodes, amperage

I have a question, I lately got a diode from an electrical device, and I'd like to use it with an Arduino, so I wanted to know the operating voltage of the diode (a LED), is there any way to get the voltage and amph of a diode?

Comment: Can you tell what it was connected to in the device you got it from? That may give you a typical operating condition.

Comment: Also, does it have some kind of color code on it? See http://www.tpub.com/neets/book7/24k.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most can operate safely with 10-15 mA and are often useful with much lower currents.

To find the approximate Vf, connect the diode in series with a 470 ohm resistor to a 5V supply. In one direction it will light, in the other it will remain off (assuming it's a simple single junction device). With it lit, measure Vf with a multimeter. That will give you the Vf at the current (5V-Vf)/470 ohms.

Usually red LEDs are around 2V Vf (a bit more for super red) and most other colors are closer to 3V (especially blue and white and 'UV') . Infrared LEDs are more like 1.2V.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to know the forward voltage, your average multimeter should have a diode test setting. It should use the same terminals as for voltage and resistance, and the symbol on the range switch will just be a diode symbol. Some meters combine diode test and continuity, as well. If your multimeter doesn't have a specified diode test current (check the meter's datasheet), follow the procedure below instead if you want a precise measurement.

If it's an LED, it's possible the forward voltage may be too high for your meter to measure. In that case, simply connect the diode through a resistor to a 5V source, or to a power supply in constant-current mode (set to no more than 10~20mA, and still use a resistor! As Spehro pointed out in the comments, there might be a capacitive discharge at higher current that could damage your diode.), and measure the voltage across the diode with your meter.

Comment: This might work, however the Vf will be at a rather low (and unknown current), and on my multimeter the display goes overrange above 1.999V so it's not going to work for any color but red (and IR). More critically, I would not suggest connecting an LED directly to a power supply in CC mode- the output may have a capacitor across it and it will discharge through the LED possibly damaging it. It's okay with a series resistor or if you gradually bring the voltage up with current limiting set to something reasonable.

Comment: I hadn't meant put it in without a resistor. I should clarify that. Also, I thought multimeters specified their diode test currents? Of course, I suppose that's not always the case.

Comment: @Fethry +1 You are correct, it certainly should be in the manual. My manual says (approximately) 1mA and it actually varies almost 2:1 over the range. 100 ohms should be okay for the resistor.